# Допустима ли фраза?

Tags: фразеология

Есть ли ошибка во фразе "быть тебе верна"? 
Вот полностью четверостишие:
Я не жалею ни о том,
        что было,
И то, что будет – всё
         приму сполна.
Я не прошу о том –
        недостижимом, 
Я лишь прошу, чтоб
        быть тебе верна.

Answer (score 1):

Интересное стихотворение, очень искреннее, но немного недоработанное. Есть  удачные, свежие образы, но есть  и то, что хотелось бы переделать.Например:

(1)Прости, что беспардонно наблюдаю, И по-шпионски следую порой, И взглядом до калитки провожаю, Напротив прячась за густой листвой. Слова "беспардонно", "по-шпионски" не очень вписываются в общую лирическую тональность; кроме того, в сочетании "напротив прячась за густой листвой" кажется нарушенным размер, подошло бы, например, "скрываясь за зеленою листвой" или что-то в этом роде.

(2) Я лишь прошу, чтоб быть тебе верна. В правильности этого выражения я сильно сомневаюсь.
Можно было бы, например,  сказать: "Пусть снится сон, где я тебя верна".

Comment: Толковые замечания.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ, он очень конструктивен и доброжелателен! 
Но героиня спать не хочет. Не надеясь на взаимность она решает, что не вправе потерять (или уничтожить,обменять, продать и пр.) своё чувство. 
Это больше похоже на сказку конечно.

Comment: А если так: Пусть жизнь как сон, где я тебе верна. Мне кажется, что читатель нормально воспримет не слишком ясный смысл, который он додумает сам и который придаст стихотворению некую загадочность и объемность. Но в то же время он не склонен прощать значительные отклонения в грамматической форме.

Comment: Согласна, что есть грамматическая корявость, да и не совсем верное употребление слова "сполна"-сполна расплачиваются, а не принимают. Может, поменять на что-то вроде этого:
Я не жалею ни о чём, что было,
 Пусть будет всё как будет – в муке смертной
Я не прошу о том – недостижимом ,
Прошу лишь разрешить тебе быть верной.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза неграмотная. Во-первых: быть какой? - верной. 
"Я лишь прошу, чтоб быть тебе верной" - это бессмысленно, на мой взгляд, и в контексте стихотворения - тоже. Можно, конечно, придумывать еще какие-то слова до и после, чтобы придать этому ужасу смысл:

Я лишь прошу денег, чтоб быть тебе верной, а то пойду на панель.
Я лишь прошу не отправлять меня к твоему другу одну, и это я прошу, чтоб остаться (остаться, не быть!) тебе верной.
Я лишь прошу не заставлять меня свидетельствовать против тебя в суде, чтоб быть тебе верной.

...самым логичным мне кажется последний вариант.

Comment: Напрасно вы так резко. Передать все оттенки человеческих чувств и отношений - задача сложная. Иногда они настолько нелогичны, что не укладываются в обычные формы, и тогда нужен поиск, и нужны особые приемы. Можно привести такое суждение: я не стал поэтом, потому что критический ум во мне был сильнее моего поэтического чувства. Это очень верно: когда слова и образы только рождаются, они еще несовершенны, и лучше писать дальше и не думать пока о форме. Иногда такое чувство-образ имеет большую ценность, даже если его запись неидеальна. Чаще бывает, что записывать нечего.

Comment: "...что записывать нечего." Это вы на меня что ль намекаете? Не обо мне речь. Вы правда считаете, что стихи хороши? Я за то, чтобы прекрасно было не только содержание, но и форма.

Поскольку справа мне светила тьма. - Это находка в самом деле, тут я согласна.

тут я умолкаю. Ибо сказано: править вопрос, а не добавлять комментарии.

Comment: "...что записывать нечего." Это вы на меня что ль намекаете? Не обо мне речь. Вы правда считаете, что стихи хороши? Я за то, чтобы прекрасно было не только содержание, но и форма.

Поскольку справа мне светила тьма. - Это находка в самом деле, тут я согласна.
но я умолкаю. Ибо сказано: править вопрос, а не добавлять комментарии.

Comment: Как я могу на Вас намекать, если я Ваших стихов не читала. Я про поэзию говорю. Погрешности формы  можно исправить, а вот найти тему и хотя бы набросать эскиз художественного пространства не всегда получается. К тому же автор просил нас высказаться по поводу грамматики, а не содержания, а про грамматику достаточно было коротко сказать, в чем она нарушена.

Comment: Спасибо за урок грамматики, но позвольте с Вами не согласиться по поводу Вашего высказывания : "Я лишь прошу, чтоб быть тебе верной" - это бессмысленно, на мой взгляд, и в контексте стихотворения - тоже. Можно, конечно, придумывать еще какие-то слова до и после, чтобы придать этому ужасу смысл... 
Дело в том, что Вы просто не поняли Кого девушка просит. Отнюдь не человека, которого любит. Она вообще с ним не общается. Я о Боге говорю. Поскольку Бог есть Любовь, то Он её и дарит. А любящий по-настоящему человек любовь потерять боится и старается сберечь её своей чистой жизнью.

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, со стихами можно на Стихи.ру.
Там авторам всё про их стихи расскажут. ;))

Comment: Поскольку там никто ничего не сказал, поэтому я сюда написал.

Comment: А здесь Вам дали чёткий ответ: фраза, пардон, корявая.